# Ionic switch view when click on link

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

In my HTML view I have a link like this:

```
 <a class="club-tab-item" href="#" ng-show="club.Facebook" ng-click="openFacebook(club.Facebook)">
     <i class="icon ion-social-facebook" style="color:#3b5998"></i>
 </a>
```

My current state is "app.associazione". When I click the link I open facebook page from controller:

```
 $scope.openFacebook = function (mUrl) {
    window.open(mUrl, '_system', 'location=yes');
};
```

When I click, the link opens but my view changes to "login" defined in stateProvider config. This is my app.js file:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})

.state('disclaimer', {
    url: "/disclaimer",
    templateUrl: "templates/disclaimer.html",
    controller: 'DisclaimerCtrl'
})


.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
})

.state('app.tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: "templates/tab.html"
        }
    }
})
.state('app.tab.associazione', {
     url: "/associazione/:associazioneId",
     views: {
         'tab-eventi': {
             templateUrl: "templates/associazione.html",
             controller: 'AssociazioneCtrl'
         }
     }
 })
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
});
```

I'm newbie, sorry! Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link opens " # " URL as defined in `href="#"` and by default any URL not defined will be interpreted as login URL as you defined `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');`
Was that your question?

Comment: Yes Wael, you're right!!! Simply delete the href statement!! I really appreciate your help!! Thank you very very much for helping me! :)